# View com filtros e grid em Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Sou novato em Asp.Net MVC e preciso criar uma View parecida com a imagem a seguir:

[image: Exemplo da tela]

No quadro "Filtros" o usuário irá selecionar os filtros a serem utilizados na consulta e clicar no botão "Filtrar" para trazer os dados.

Os dados irão compor uma lista e serão apresentadas em algum controle que simule um grid (se possível com barra de rolagem ou paginada mesmo).

Abaixo um quadro que terá algumas opções, como um botão para criar um novo chamado.

Minha dificuldade é que não sei por onde começar, pois após a realização do filtro eu não queria que os filtros selecionados se apagassem ou tivesse seu valor alterado para o padrão.

E não sei se a parte do grid deverá ser uma view partial.

Alguém pra me dar um norte?

Comment: Tem alguns plugin que já fazem isso como: DataTables, jQuery Bootgrid, etc ... Eu recomendo usar DataTables: https://datatables.net/

Comment: Tem tutorial passo a passo de como fazer (parecido com a sua, a ideia é mesma). Nesse link: https://www.youtube.com/user/achillesfroes/videos tem todos exemplos.  Acessa lá que lá vai explicar direitinho.

Comment: Opa, vou acessar agora, obrigado @MatheusMiranda!

Comment: Começa com esse vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WtswNaE5OgI e assim por diante... Qualquer coisa só escrever no comentário.